# Are static Broadcast Receivers inefficient?

Tags: android, performance, broadcastreceiver

Unlike dynamically registered Broadcast Receivers, the ones registered in the manifest are able to respond to events even after the activity or even the app that created it has been closed.

So, my questions are:

- Every time there is an event, is an instance of every broadcast receiver registered for that event created? (even if the app is not running anymore)
- In that case, isn´t it a performance issue? Potentially every time there is an event the system might have to recreate a bunch of old broadcast receivers just to handle that event.

I know the developer should be responsible, but since potentially this is possible to do, why does the system allow this outside the lifecycle of an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Android 8 implicit broadcasts no longer work except for those [ones](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts).

So unless the package is explicitly set on the intent to have your package, your package will not receive the broadcast. The link above explains in more details.

Comment: Thanks for that, so just to clarify: 
- Implicit broadcasts can only be declared dynamic.
- Explicit broadcasts can only be declared static.